# Multiple modals not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I apologize if this is been answered before but I've been staring at this code for hours and cant figure out why it is behaving the way it is.

I have a page with 3 modal windows on it that I am using javascript to trigger. Now with just one modal window it works fine, however I have tried adding two more windows and the first link for the first window triggers the third modal and then the close function does not work anymore.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal1 {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal2 {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Modal Header */
.modal-header {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

/* Modal Body */
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

/* Modal Footer */
.modal-footer {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: animatetop;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
from {top: -300px; opacity: 0} 
to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
from {top: -300px; opacity: 0}
to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}
</style>
```

HTML & Javascript:

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Open Modal 1</a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn1">Open Modal 2</a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn2">Open Modal 3</a>

<!-- modal 1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
            function modalFun(){
                // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
                btn.onclick = function() {
                    console.log(modal);
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

                     // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");


                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
                btn.onclick = function() {
                    console.log(modal1);
                    modal1.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    modal1.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal1) {
                        modal1.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

                     // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");


                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
                btn.onclick = function() {
                    console.log(modal2);
                    modal2.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    modal2.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal2) {
                        modal2.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }

            window.onload=modalFun;
       </script>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
<p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Modal 1 -->

<!-- Modal 2 -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal1">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2>Modal Header2</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
<p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->

<!-- Modal 3 -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2>Modal Header3</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
<p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Modal 3 -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` returns the first `.close` in the document every single time. You need to grab the `.close` that matches your individual modals. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is a great tool for this. Try

```
var span = modal.querySelector('.close');
```

to get the correct one. You're also using `.onclick` to setup your event handlers. It's better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Also, you're duplicating a lot of code and changing what `modal` refers to. It'd be better to move that functionality into a function.

```
function initializeModal(modalID, buttonID) {
  // Get the modal element
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalID);

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById(buttonID);

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = modal.querySelector('.close');

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  });

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  });

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

Bringing it all together:

```js
function initializeModal(modalID, buttonID) {
  // Get the modal element
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalID);

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById(buttonID);

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = modal.querySelector('.close');

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  });

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  });

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  initializeModal('myModal', 'myBtn');
  initializeModal('myModal1', 'myBtn1');
  initializeModal('myModal2', 'myBtn2');
});
```

```css
/* Reuse this class for each modal */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Modal Header */

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
/* Modal Body */

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
/* Modal Footer */

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Open Modal 1</a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn1">Open Modal 2</a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn2">Open Modal 3</a>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal 3 -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, I don't know why I didn't think to use addEventListener and querySelector. This also explains why the close function wasn't working on the third modal (because it was trying to close the first one still). Thanks so much! @mike-c

Comment: @holodout You got it! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You code is not at all correct you are redeclaring the variables with in the same function.
Because of that btn is binded to the last modal at the end of the function
Use different variables like btn,btn1,btn2

Also 
`var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`
This will always be binded to the first one you will have to use different ID for the close button too..

I suggest you use bootstrap-modal your code will become much cleaner
This is not a good approach

Here is a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/c9ftdgum/

Comment: @mike-c has answered it in a better way you can see his answer it will also clean the code

Answer (score 0):

Hey so i struggled with this for a few days,
I knew my modals worked because they performed as expected when testing on individual webpages.
When i combined all 3 of my modals to one webpage, it all broke. So this is what i found out after days of testing and debugging.
Placement of your MODAL matters!!

Firstly, your buttons for modal triggers can be all placed in one parent div, the modals however should be defined outside that parent div.
EX

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role='button'data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal1">Modal 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role='button'data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal2">Modal 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role='button'data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal3">Modal 3</a>
</div>
```

!! IMPORTANT PART !!

NOW we can define the modals BUT in reverse order of the buttons.
so the first modal we define should be for the last button (#modal3), then the middle buttons modal will be defined (#modal2), and the last modal we will define will be for the first button.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

IDK why the order matters but it works.
So if your sure the code for your modal triggers and modal is correct
but the screen fades when you click the modal button,
try this.
Hope it helps someone and saves countless hours of debugging.